# SSH authentication

Tags: bash, ssh, scripting, authentication, azure

I am trying to make ssh on VM have an authentication before the user is connected to the session. Right now I have an Azure MFA app, that when the user authenticates, it shows a password. I want this password to be the one that the user enters to connect, but the password will be different every time to keep the security of the VM.

So the problem is how can I make the password that the MFA app generates be the password to the SSH connection where the password will be changed automatically after each session?

Let me explain the process:

1. the user types the command "ssh hostname@ip"
2. the terminal is then prompted to follow a link where the user can authenticate themself. When they have successfully authenticated themself, they get the password for this SSH connection
3. they enter the password from the link.

I have the MFA app, and I have an SSH connection established. I tried to use the ForceCommand option in the sshd_config file, but the script runs after the ssh is established. I want it before it is established.

Comment: Have you considered using standard MFA, where you get prompted for the current generator value? People understand that - it's now pretty common usage and expectation so you're not having to teach anyone anything new

Comment: yea this is the standard mfa, I just want to add that to the ssh

Comment: Your description sounds nothing like standard MFA